# Como fazer com que cada input fique em uma linha separadamente?

Tags: html5, css3

Tenho este `HTML` e gostaria que cada `input` fique em linhas separadas, neste caso abaixo que eu tivesse 3 linhas, uma para cada `input`.

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #1C1C1C;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.log-adm{
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.log-adm-campos{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" name="loguin" class="log-adm">
<input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário" required="required" class="log-adm-campos">
<input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required="required" class="log-adm-campos">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É assim que você quer? você pode usar o `display: block`, ou ate mesmo o `float: left;` (dependendo da situação), mas em geral só precisa da primeira opção.

Um elemento com valor `block` é chamado de elemento de nível de bloco ou apenas elemento de bloco. Um elemento com valor `inline` é sempre chamado de elemento de linha.

```css
input{
  display: block;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" name="loguin" class="log-adm">
<input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário" required="required" class="log-adm-campos">
<input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required="required" class="log-adm-campos">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Só que ficaram alinhados a esquerda, para centralizar eu faço o que? Não funcionou text-align: center/

Comment: Vou editar a resposta @Gladison

Comment: Pronto, testa agora

Comment: continua o alinhamento a esquerda. Gostaria de centralizado também os inputs. Rsss

Comment: Executa meu exemplo, ele esta no `centro`, agora preciso entender o porque o seu não está

Comment: Deu certo!!! Perfeito! Show

Comment: @Gladison Legal ;) pode marcar como resolvido

Answer (score 2):

Somente com CSS, mesmo código que o seu:

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #1C1C1C;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.log-adm{
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.log-adm-campos{
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" name="loguin" class="log-adm">
<input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário" required="required" class="log-adm-campos">
<input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required="required" class="log-adm-campos">
<input type="submit" class="log-adm-campos">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias formas você pode fazer por CSS utilizando [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```
input {
  display: block;
}
```

Você pode divir os elementos em [Div](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)

```css
.log-adm {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" name="loguin" class="log-adm">

<div>
  <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário" required="required" class="log-adm-campos">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required="required" class="log-adm-campos">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="submit">
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<form action="" method="post" name="loguin" class="log-adm">
  <p><input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário" required="required" class="log-adm-campos"></p>
  <p><input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required="required" class="log-adm-campos"></p>
  <p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Depois disso só brincar com os `padding`.

Answer (score -1):

É só usar  para quebrar a linha!

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #1C1C1C;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.log-adm{
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.log-adm-campos{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" name="loguin" class="log-adm">
<input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário" required="required" class="log-adm-campos"></br>
<input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required="required" class="log-adm-campos"></br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `</br>` não existe. O Correto é `<br />`.